# Twitter Bootstrap fluid spans broke template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When i try to get a table with spans. I get fluid table.
How to get a flat table without these strange spaces?
Picture to explain what wrong:

[image: Fluid table]

Full listing of sourse page https://gist.github.com/2984012

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No space at the beginning

#### Problem

The space that appears on the 3rd line is a "feature" of bootstrap : the first span of a container has no left margin.

```css
[class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

(source : https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L613)

#### Fix

You can add an invisible .span element before the first item : that way the first item will have a space too.

```
<div class="span" style="display: none;"></div>
```

### Hole in the layout

#### Problem

Your first item seems to be longer (in height).

#### Fix

It appears you have set a minimum height, but you should fix a **maximum height**, or ensure that there are **no items longer** than the minimum height.

Comment: But there's very interesting thing: if i set "span3" I can get just 3 items per line. But if apply "first-child" to each 4-th item. We can get 4! item per line. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/208/22333290.jpg/

Comment: @itsnikolay you should try daniel glenn answer about using the `thumbnail` class instead of the invisible element.

Answer (score 5):

you using the class **thumbnails** but not the child class **thumbnail** for the items in your code.

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <!-- start item -->
    <li class="span3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#" title="" ><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt=""></a>
        <h5><a href="#" title="" >Ruby on Rails Ringer</a></h5>
    <p>$17.99</p>
    </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end item -->    
</ul>
</div>
```

second you don't need the class **row-fluid** because thumbnails class using fluid out of the box.

```
<div class="">
  <div data-hook="homepage_products">
```

last point - I don't see your container in your code

```
<div class="container">
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linuxbender/m6CNd/)

Comment: It uses <div class="container-fluid">. But it still doesn't work well http://jsfiddle.net/linuxbender/m6CNd/