# Bootstrap multiple rows of spans in a row-fluid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout, grid-layout

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179524/twitter-bootstrap-fluid-spans-broke-template) is very similar, although it doesn't answer my question.

[An answer like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318677/multiple-spans-per-row-in-twitter-bootstrap) would be fine, as long as it works for responsive layouts e.g. `.row-fluid`, which it doesn't at the moment.

Is it possible in Bootstrap to have one fluid row and multiple rows within that row like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
        </div>
        <div class="span12">
        </div>
        <div class="span12">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

without the second row of spans having an odd margin-left?

[Click here for a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nwhQf/9/)

Essentially what I need is to have multiple rows of spans inside a `.row-fluid` without the rows after the first breaking the layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well the displacement is caused by a margin-left.

It's not ideal but you could always override the CSS:

```
.container-fluid .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

Acutally though, the error seems to lie in the fact that you've declared 12 span3 DIVs, which adds up to a total of 36. 12 is the limit for a fluid container, so you'd need to make those span1:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span1">1
        </div>
        <div class="span1">2
        </div>
        <div class="span1">3
        </div>
        <div class="span1">4
        </div>
        <div class="span1">5
        </div>
        <div class="span1">6
        </div>
        <div class="span1">7
        </div>
        <div class="span1">8
        </div>
        <div class="span1">9
        </div>
        <div class="span1">10
        </div>
        <div class="span1">11
        </div>
        <div class="span1">12
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7Lu43/51/

Comment: I know the total is more than 12, it was kind of the point :p I was trying to get around having a `.row-fluid` for each 12 spans

Comment: @Mackwerk  Haha, ah I see :o 
Well the margin override should be correct then isn't it?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for not accepting your answer. Also, if you do `margin-left:1%` instead of `0` it actually looks good aswell, and it fits!

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap 3 it is possible to insert several (.span) within a same row. What I find most interesting, does not break the layout and works the responsiveness. In bootstrap 2 you have to obey the limete of 12 columns for each row. If this limit is exceeded, the margins contained in the other columns hinder the layout.

For my case I cleaned the column margins and inserted margins only for the right columns:

> Exemple - layout 2 Column

```
.myDiv{
  .span6{
    margin-left:0;
    &:nth-child(even){
      margin-left: 2.127659574468085%;
    }
  }
}
```

> and responsive 767px

```
@media  (max-width: 767px) {
  .myDiv{
    .span6{
      margin-left:0;
      &:nth-child(even){
        margin-left: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```